# Vertically centering a UITextField's attributedPlaceholder

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am currently unable to vertically align an attributedPlaceholder inside a UITextField and I've no idea why.

Here's what I am doing:

```
self.addressBar = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(...)];
self.addressBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.addressBar.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Placeholder text"
                                attributes:@{
                                             NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor colorWithRed:79/255.0f green:79/255.0f blue:79/255.0f alpha:0.5f],
                                             NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"Gotham-BookItalic" size:14.0],
                                             }
 ];
self.addressBar.delegate = self;
self.addressBar.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
[self.view addSubview:self.addressBar];
```

And here's what happening:

[image: The UITextFieldLabel is smaller than its parent]

It's quite clear that this happens due to the fact that the UITextFieldLabel's height is 10px smaller than the UItextField itself, but I can't seem change that.

This only happens using an attributedPlaceholder though; the default placeholder property works just fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Default placeholder has a same font size as a textfield's font. That's why it's centered.

Comment: OK makes sense but isn't there another way to center the placeholder while maintaining that font size?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `NSParagraphStyle` to increase minimum line height:

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [self.addressBar.defaultTextAttributes[NSParagraphStyleAttributeName] mutableCopy];
style.minimumLineHeight = self.addressBar.font.lineHeight - (self.addressBar.font.lineHeight - [UIFont fontWithName:@"Gotham-BookItalic" size:14.0].lineHeight) / 2.0;

self.addressBar.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Placeholder text"
                            attributes:@{
                                         NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor colorWithRed:79/255.0f green:79/255.0f blue:79/255.0f alpha:0.5f],
                                         NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"Gotham-BookItalic" size:14.0],
                                         NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : style
                                         }
 ];
```

You could also override a `- (CGRect)placeholderRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds;` method in `UITextField` subclass.

It's messy, but it works :)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks :) I'll award you the bounty as soon as I can (15h from now)

Comment: for Xcode 9+ and Swift 4+ instead of `NSParagraphStyleAttributeName` *use* 
 `NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle`

Answer (score 2):

Placeholder will not be aligned if your textfield's text font is different than that of textfield's placeholder's font. Make sure both the font are same if you want to align properly or else you can follow kean's answer.

```
    textField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:12];
    textField.attributedPlaceholder =
    [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Enter fruit/vegetable name"
                                                                           attributes:@{
                                                                                            NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:12.0]
                                                                                        }
     ];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using attributedPlaceholder, make sure to set the font of the textField to be the same font you use in the attributedString.

Answer (score 1):

As @Kean answered. And you should do it like this in Swift 4:

```
let defaultParagraphValue = self.textField.defaultTextAttributes[NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle.rawValue]
if let lineHeight = self.textField.font?.lineHeight,
   let style = defaultParagraphValue as? NSParagraphStyle,
   let mutableStyle = style.mutableCopy() as? NSMutableParagraphStyle {

    mutableStyle.minimumLineHeight = lineHeight - (lineHeight - UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16).lineHeight) / 2.0
    let placeholderAttribute =  [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16),
                                 NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle: mutableStyle]
    let attributeHolder = NSAttributedString(string: "Placeholder String",
                                             attributes: placeholderAttribute)
    self.textField.attributedPlaceholder = attributeHolder
}
```

This works in iOS 10, iOS 11 fix this issue.